# ftp_delete does not work -> "1 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource..."

Tags: php, ftp

I've following code to upload a file via ftp in a html form.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
// $ftp_server = "xxx";
$ftp_server = 'xxx';
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxx";

//setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
//login
if(ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
  {
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
 else {
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}
$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
$remote_file_path = "/import/".$file;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";



include("writedb.php"); 

if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {
 echo "$file deltet successful.\n";
} else {
 echo "cant delete: $file\n";
}

?>
```

Everythings works except the deleting of the uploaded file.

The error is like this:

```
Warning: ftp_delete(): 1 is not a valid FTP Buffer resource in   (correct path) on line 29
cant delete: daten.csv
```

What is wrong in my code?

Thank you guys :)

Comment: You're trying to delete after you close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the -> if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {

to if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $remote_file_path)) {

because you arn not in the right directory

I hope that works !!

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your connection before you attempt to delete the file; this will obviously not work. That's why it says it is not a valid resource (any more).

Delete first, then close the connection.

Comment: Oh, right thank you! Now there is another error:  Could not delete daten.csv: No such file or directory in /upload_file.php on line 27, line 27: if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $file)) {

Comment: Try this: `if (ftp_delete($conn_id, $remote_file_path))`.